# Kolmogorov Smirnov Test in Spark (Python) not working?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, kolmogorov-smirnov

I was doing a normality test in Python spark-ml and saw what I *think* is an bug.

Here is the setup, i have a data-set that is normalized (range -1, to 1).

When I do a histogram, i can clearly see that the data is NOT normal:

```
>>> prices_norm.histogram(10)

([-1.0, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
 [226, 269, 119, 95, 52, 26, 8, 2, 2, 5])
```

When I run the Kolmgorov-Smirnov test I get the following results:

```
>>> testResults = Statistics.kolmogorovSmirnovTest(prices_norm, "norm")
>>> print testResults

Kolmogorov-Smirnov test summary:
degrees of freedom = 0 
statistic = 0.46231145770077375 
pValue = 1.742039845709087E-11 
Very strong presumption against null hypothesis: Sample follows theoretical distribution.
```

The Kolmgorov-Smirnov test defines the *null hypothesis (H0)* as: *the data follows a specified distribution* (http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm).

In this case the p-value is very low, so we should reject the null hypothesis.  This makes sense, as it is clearly not normal.

So why then, does it say:

```
Sample follows theoretical distribution
```

Isn't this wrong?  Shouldn't it say that the sample does NOT follow a theoretical distribution?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think `Sample follows theoretical distribution.` just restates the null hypothesis.

Comment: What is the output if the data actually does follow a normal distribution?

Comment: @siwica, you are correct, it was just restating the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was driving me crazy, so I went to look at the source code directly:

```
git://git.apache.org/spark.git
spark/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/stat/test/KolmogorovSmirnovTest.scala
```

The code is **correct**, the null Hypothesis is set as:

```
object NullHypothesis extends Enumeration {
  type NullHypothesis = Value
  val OneSampleTwoSided = Value("Sample follows theoretical distribution")
}
```

The verbiage of the string message is just **restating the null hypothesis**:

```
Very strong presumption against null hypothesis: Sample follows theoretical distribution.
                                                 ________________________________________
                                                                    H0
```

Arguably the verbiage is confusing as it could be interpreted both ways.  But it is indeed correct.